# If $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$ & $y \in (-1,1)$ , then $x^2 \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+(1-y^2)\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0$ represents?

Tags: partial-derivative, conic-sections

For $-\infty<x< \infty$ and $-1<y<1$,the partial differential equation
$$x^2 \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+(1-y^2)\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0$$ represents _____?

My Approach:
We know general form of $2nd$ order differential eq. is:
$$Au_{xx}+2Hu_{xy}+Bu_{yy}+2Gu_x+2Fu_y+Cu=K$$
if $H^2=AB$ ,then it represents parabola
if $H^2<AB$ ,then it represents ellipse
& if $H^2>AB$ ,then it represents hyperbola
In this problem:
$A=x^2$ & $B=(1-y^2)$ ;also $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$ & $y \in (-1,1)$
then how can we interprets its curve?
please help...

Comment: What is the value of $H$?

Comment: we know that $x$ is a real number, so $x^2\ge0$, we also know that $|y|$ is strictly less than $1$, so $1>|y|>y^2$ thus $1-y^2>0$. $A$ is positive and $B$ is strictly positive so $AB\ge0$, now, $H$ is...?